# How to execute if statement written in a perl subroutine

Tags: perl, if-statement

I have written a perl subroutine where I'm using two if statements. When I call this subroutine the control goes into the subroutine, prints the xml but does not go inside the if statements.

```
sub send_msg {
    my ($type,$name,$number,$email,$testid) = @_;
    my $xml = qq{<tolist><to>}
            . qq{<name>$name</name>}
            . qq{<contactpersonname>$name</contactpersonname>}
            . qq{<number>$number</number>} 
            . qq{<email>$email</email>} 
            . qq{</to></tolist>}
            . qq{<from>}
            . qq{<name>$name</name>};
    $xml .= qq{<number>$number</number>}if($type eq 0);
    $xml .= qq{<email>$email</email>}if($type eq 1);
    $xml .= qq{</from>};
  print "\ntype : $type\n";
  print "\nxml :$xml\n"; 


   if ($type == 1)
  {  print"Inside type1";
    $sql3 = "select text from test where TestId='$testid'";
    $sth3 = $dbh->prepare($sql3);
    $sth3->execute
    or die "SQL Error: $DBI::errstr\n";
    my ($message) = $sth3->fetchrow_array();
    my $targetxml="<shorttext>".$message."</shorttext>";
    print "\n $targetxml \n";

  }

   if ($type == 0)
  {
   print "Inside type 0\n"; 
   $sql5 = "select testText,testTitle from test where TestId='$testid'";
   $sth5 = $dbh->prepare($sql5);
   $sth5->execute
   or die "SQL Error: $DBI::errstr\n";
   my ($subject,$title) = $sth5->fetchrow_array(); 
   my $mailxml="";
   $mailxml=$mailxml."<subject>".$title."</subject>";
   $mailxml=$mailxml."<body>".$subject."</body>";
   $mailxml=$mailxml."<type>html</type>";
   print "\n$mailxml\n";

  }
}
```

In the above code,I'm calling the subroutine using `send_msg(1,Joe,91.97451214551,rich@r.in,32);`.
$xml and $type gets printed but why is it failing to enter the if statements.

Comment: Sorry about that....I had deleted it...but still does not execute..

Comment: Then `$type` is neither 0 nor 1.

Comment: @Jens $type can be both 0 and 1 and depends the subroutine call.

Comment: @Vishu I'm telling you it isn't. And if it were, one of the two ifs would be called. We question your diagnose. What happens if the second `if` were an unconditional `else` instead?

Comment: @Mat Mat I'm calling the subroutine with the same parameters. I told you it is executing till printing $xml $type but not beyond

Comment: What does it print for `$type`? Note that `" 0 "` is not a 0, print it with some delimiters, like `print "type = <$type>"`;

Comment: @Jens I used elsif instead of another if statement. It executes.

Comment: @Jens Jens, as you told it is working with else but not if

Comment: @Vishu **And that tells us that `$type` is neither 0 nor 1.** Do you understand that? Whoever calls send_msg provides a different value as the first arg. Not 0. Not 1. Maybe 2. Maybe an empty string.

Comment: @Mat Here is the exact call -  send_msg($type,$name,$number,$email,$testid);

Comment: @Jens From the main code $type can take either 0 or 1 as its value

Comment: @Vishu That's what you *think* it does, but it obviously doesn't. Print $type with delimiters like I suggest in my answer. Anything else will not lead us to the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Of course not. There's a `return` statement before the `if`. Something left over from debugging?

Happens to the best of us. :-)

**Edit** after OP fixed the code:

Your `$type` is neither a numeric 0 nor a numeric 1. You should print it with delimiters like

```
print "length($type) = ". length($type) . "\n";
print "type = <$type>\n";
```

Next, reduce your code to this:

```
sub send_msg {
   my ($type,$name,$number,$email,$testid) = @_;
   if ($type == 0) {
     print "type is 0\n";
   }
   elsif ($type == 1) {
     print "type is 1\n";
   }
   else {
     print "type is neither 0 nor 1, but <$type>\n";
   }
}
```

I don't think this is the bug, but I note that you use

```
... if($type eq 0);
```

in another place, which is not a numeric comparison (==), but a string comparison (eq).

Comment: No...I deleted it...still the if statements are not executed

Comment: Then `$type` is neither 0 nor 1.

Comment: This was the output for the above prints length(0) = 1
type = <0>

Comment: @Mat Jens Any other solution can you suggest me

Comment: Any chance of actual code being `if ($type = 0)` when it should be `if ($type == 0)`?

Comment: No, Jens I have written properly. See now the else part is executing, but the first if statement is not executing

Comment: Please reduce your code as shown above and tell us the output.

Comment: Now add your original code, line after line, until it breaks.